# Repeater: databind server-side ID in item control?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

When binding a datasource to a Repeater control, is it possible to databind to the ID property of a server-side control inside the ItemTemplate? like so:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptToolTips" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <telerik:RadToolTip ID="tt<%# Eval("Name") %>" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
            <div class="tip">
                <div class="segName">Segment #<%# Eval("Name") %></div>
                <div>Flow:<%# Eval("Flow", "{0:N}") %></div>
            </div>
        </telerik:RadToolTip>

    </ItemTemplate>     
</asp:Repeater>
```

...here I'm trying to set the RadToolTip's ID property to "tt[name-value]". I've tried a few variants but they're invalid:

```
ID="tt<%# Eval("Name") %>"

ID='tt<%# Eval("Name") %>'

ID="tt<%# Eval('Name') %>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. A server control's ID is set at the time it's being created or at design time. Once it's set you cannot reset it during the data binding.

But, if you are trying to use this ID value in `JQuery` or `JavaScript` you could employ the following hack.

Add a custom property to your control (give it any name you like and in this case I'll use **myId**)

```
myId='<%# Eval("Name") %>'
```

No you can find this element by this `myId` property

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. i had hoped the nested controls were being created at the time of databind, and thus their ID could be set the same as when using a static string for the ID (which works)...but sounds like it's not that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to assign ID

ID=' "tt" + <%# Eval("Name") %>'

Comment: did you try that? it's not valid.

Comment: sorry but in this moment can not try. Try this id='<%# Eval("name","tt{0}") %>'

Comment: i dont think thats going to work as it's the same syntax as my failed attempts. im not really looking for suggestions, im asking if anyone knows whether it's possible. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049483/validatiing-a-textbox-in-a-gridview-using-javascript-on-onchange-event-not-work/26051333#26051333) answer by me to one of the questions at SO for another way (using pure JavaScript's `this` object rather than using a custom property to get the clientID) of doing this.

Just thought of keeping these linked for future reference.